# What's the best way to test the child of a child?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

So I'm currently in the middle of learning how to unit test my components, and what I have works, but I don't feel like it's the "right" way to do it.

In my last two tests, I'm looking for the first child of the first child.  That feels a little bit dirty, but I'm struggling to find a better way of achieving this.

Essentially what I was to do is test if the svg is present in that scenario - And if not, in the next test, if the text is present.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

**My Component Output:**

```
<h1>
  <svg...> <!--(if hasIcon prop is set to true)-->
  My Header Text
</h1>
```

**My Current Tests:**

```
let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = render(<MyComponent />);
});


describe("<MyComponent />", () => {
    it("should render", () => {
        const { container } = wrapper;
        expect(container.firstChild);
    });

    it("should match snapshot", () => {
        const { container } = wrapper;
        expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it("should render with an icon", () => {
        const { container } = wrapper;
        expect(container.firstChild.firstChild.nodeName).toBe("svg");
    });

    it("should render without an icon", () => {
        const { container } = render(<AppHeader hasIcon={false} />);
        expect(container.firstChild.firstChild.nodeName).toBe("#text");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you attach a data-testid attribute to the svg and the text parent element and then just use queryByTestId to assert that the element is there?

Comment: @Win Would that go directly onto my component?  Outside of the test file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding from my comment above, here's an approach that you can take as your main concern revolves around `container.firstChild.firstChild.nodeName`

```
const Text = () => <p data-testid="text">Some text</p>;
const SVG = () => <svg data-testid="svg>Some svg</svg>;

const MyComponent = ({ text = false, svg = false }) => (
    <div>
        {text && <Text/>}
        {svg && <SVG/>}
    </div>
);

describe("<MyComponent />", () => {
    it("should render", () => {
        const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);
        expect(container.firstChild).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should not render text or svg", () => {
        const { queryByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />);
        expect(queryByTestId('svg')).toBeFalsy();
        expect(queryByTestId('text')).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it("should render with a text element", () => {
        const { queryByTestId } = render(<MyComponent text={true} />);;
        expect(queryByTestId('text')).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should render with a svg element", () => {
        const { queryByTestId } = render(<MyComponent svg={true} />);
        expect(queryByTestId('svg')).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Nick Great! This will also be useful if you want to set up end to end tests too since you're most likely attaching test id's to elements that you want to interact with :)